# Why can't I use "GeForce 9500 GT" for GPU rendering with Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

So I have an "NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT" GPU and I have installed CUDA so the viewport of the blender is working with this GPU, but when I try to use it for GPU Computing (GPU Rendering with Cycles), **both with CUDA, OptiX and OpenCL** it says my GPU isn't compatible and uses the CPU for rendering.

*The GPU's Capabilities:*

- Video Memory: 1GB
- DirectX 10
- OpenGL 3.3

**How do I fix that and have faster renders when using Cycles engine?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT is from the [GeForce 9 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_9_series), which doesn't fulfill the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender 2.8x.

> **Supported Graphics Cards**
>
> - **NVIDIA**: GeForce 400 and newer, Quadro Tesla GPU architecture and newer, with NVIDIA drivers (list of all [GeForce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce#GeForce_400_series_and_500_series) and [Quadro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Quadro#Quadro_FX_(with_CUDA_and_OpenCL,_but_no_Vulkan))
>     GPUs)

---

> **CUDA**
>
> CUDA requires graphics cards with compute capability 3.0 and higher.
>   To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of Nvidia graphics
>   cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with the compute capabilities and supported graphics cards.
>   CUDA GPU rendering is supported on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

It's therefore neither supported for [GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#cuda), which requires CUDA compute capability 3.0, nor for running Blender in general. The latter may still work, however given that old hardware doesn't receive driver updates anymore, you may be experiencing graphics glitches or crashes. The [latest driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/112596/en-us) available for the GeForce 9 series is from 2016.